# Unable to import Celery after deploying to Azure

Tags: python, django, azure, celery

Probably a very familiar story with predictable outcome and this will be a Path issue, but I'm at a loss to track it down.

Very simple Django app using Celery (current incarnation doesn't even attempt to run Tasks, I'm only trying to get the Django app running with the Celery module imported).

As per standard instructions. The `__init__.py` file for my project contains

```py
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals

# This will make sure the app is always imported when
# Django starts so that shared_task will use this app.

from .celery_setup import app as celery_app

__all__ = ('celery_app',)
```

Note that the usual `celery.py` is renamed `celery_setup` as other post suggested this may be a cause of the import issues.

In `celery_setup.py` the offending import statement is:

```py
from celery import Celery
```

Running locally using a `venv` no issues at all and the Celery module is picked up and loaded.

However after deploying to an Azure WebApp I can watch the log messages hitting the `wsgi.py` file only to bail out when it looks for the `Celery` module.

This is giving and error of:

`ImportError: cannot import name 'Celery' from 'celery' (/home/site/wwwroot/antenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/__init__.py)`

Using Kudu I can verify that this path exists and the file is there...

DJANGO_MODULE_SETTINGS is setup so I don't think its that.

Comment: Did you make sure that the `antenv` is actually used, not some other environment?

Comment: antenv seems to be default env when you deploy to Azure, the requirements.txt are installed to it. Strange that it appears to just be Celery as all other requirements do get picked up. I’ll maybe try loading something else in the __init__.py to see if that gets picked up properly; else I’ll be tracking down the Django boot process to determine what gets loaded/set and when...?

Comment: Investigating the docker setup (https://github.com/Azure-App-Service/python/blob/master/3.7/entrypoint.py) , the site-packages are being added as PYTHONPATH and `. antenv/bin/activate` is being called prior to GUNICORN being started. Leads me to think it's in the boot process, as to when and where Django makes 3rd part apps available...